# Django registration redux modifying registration form

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to develop a register based website. I used django registration redux for it. But I can't figure out how to modify it. As an example in default files there are username and password, I want to change username with an e-mail and add additional form to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 - customize User model:**

1.1 add next lines to your settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_accounts_app.MyUser'
```

1.2 don't forget add your application with User model to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'my_accounts_app',
)
```

1.3 write custom User model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

   # some fields here

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [...]
```

**Step 2 - customize django-registration form (if you need it):**

2.1 Write your own registration form.

2.2 Then you need to use your form. There is you can use 2 options:

a) you can write custom registration view based on registration.views.RegistrationView and pass "form_class" attribute to your view

b) OR you can set your custom registration form via passing it in your urls.py
There is the link to related django doc [Django URLconf usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf).

The default registration form is registration.forms.RegistrationForm, so don't forget to check it or use it as parent class for your custom form.

Comment: I did what you say with order but it gives error 'No module named my_accounts_app' . Did I missed something?

Comment: Did you create applicaiton with this name?

Comment: @HamlockB Create the app before adding it in the INSTALLED_APPS `python manage.py startapp my_accounts_app`.

Comment: @MarkMishyn thanks for your answers but I am very new in django so I tried to solve problem for 2 days but I couldn't. What should I write inside of required_fields[] and when I tried to enter admin it gives 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key' error. I took so many time of yours. Sorry for that

Comment: REQUIRED_FIELDS is just list of all required User fields in addition to USERNAME_FIELD and password, you can leave it empty. I guess, that your User model is invalid now, could you show your User model?